# BigCartel : {{ category.name }} and {{ artist.name }} display per item on Products page

Tags: bigcartel

I'm editing a theme in BigCartel and would like to display both the category name and the artists name underneath each product on the general 'Products' page of my BigCartel store. I have the 'Artists' category turned on (and have assigned each product to a category and an artist) and have used the code below but the names are still not displaying...They only show up when I search the store by category or Artist. (I've included 'Category' and 'X Artists Name' for styling only and will remove them once the issue is resolved.)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

[Updated 03.12.2015]

The code below works fine when viewing a specified individual category or artist, however I would like to display both the Category and Artist name on the general Products page.

```
<span class="meta-category-name">Category {{ category.name }}</span>
{% if artists.active != blank %}
<span class="meta-artist-name">X Artists Name {{ artist.name }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I worked it out - For anyone elses benefit the code below solved it.

```
{% for category in product.categories %}      
 <span class="meta-category-name">{{ category.name }}</span>
{% endfor %}

{% for artist in product.artists %}
  {% if artists.active != blank %}
 <span class="meta-artist-name">{{ artist.name }}</span>
  {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}

      </div>
```